# get_queryset and get_context_data combine functions

Tags: python, django

I am new to django i can not distinguish functions `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` in generic views. So writed this piece code:

```
class NodesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Platform
    template_name = 'project/nodes_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        child = self.request.GET.get('child')

        if child is True:
            queryset = queryset.get_family().get_descendants(include_self=True)
        elif child is False:
            queryset = queryset.get_descendants(include_self=True)
        else:
            pass
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NodesDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['nodes'] =
```

When in GET request child=False i call one function in queryset when child=False call second function. That's okay `get_queryset` logic is good. But i need show results in my template. Forloop results of queryset. So i need call function `get_context_data` and don't know what to do next.

Problem is how to forloop results of queryset, use it inside `get_context_data` function

Thanks

Comment: If i understand you correctly just do `context['nodes'] = self.get_queryset()` then `return context`

Comment: By default queryset inside a template has the default name  object_list. So i think there is no need to use the function get_context_data

Comment: A `DetailView` is used to display a single object. Are you sure you want to use that if you are trying to display multiple objects instead? Perhaps a `ListView` would be a better choice. Then you could use `object_list` in the template as @DimitrisKougioumtzis suggests and you wouldn't have to override `get_context_data`.

Comment: Also, note that `self.request.GET.get('child')` will be a string (e.g. `'True' or `'False'`) or `None`, so `child is True` and `child is False` will never be true.

Comment: why? @Alasdair explain me please. How to work with if condtions in views, if True or False

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. Do some experimenting in the view to check the value of `child`, and make sure you understand the difference between the boolean `True` and the string `'True'`.